# Data Security : OCR in Microsoft Cognitive Service API

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Microsoft Cognitive Vision api to extract text from the image stored on my local laptop using python. 
I wanted to know if the image that send to the api to extract the text is being stored once the json result is returned ?

Comment: have a look to Cognitive Services terms here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/cognitive-services-terms/

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cognitive Services Compliance and Privacy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/cognitive-services-compliance-and-privacy/) page it says:

> ...[The services] give you control over the storage and
>   deletion of any customer data that they store as part of providing the
>   services to you. For services that do not store customer data, the
>   customer data is automatically deleted after processing.

Bing services are different though. It does keep the query you search.